# Python code to execute multiple Snowflake queries in parallel

Tags: python, sql, csv, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have written a python program to fetch queries from an excel and print the output in an CSV format. The code is working fine if i run the queries sequentially one by one but of I try to use execute_async to run all the queries parallely then my code isn't working at all

Could somebody please help me out here. Below is my python code

```
            from SNOWFLAKE_CONNECTION import *
            import pandas
            
            wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r"Query_Sheet.xlsx")
            ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
            all_rows = list(ws.rows)
            cur = ctx.cursor()
            # Pull information from specific cells.
            for row in all_rows[1:4]:
                scenario = row[1].value
                query = row[2].value
                if_execute = row[3].value
                if if_execute == 'Y':
                    try:
                        cur.execute_async(query)
                        df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
                    except:
                        print(scenario," Failed")
                    else:
                        print(df)
```

All i'm getting here is Scenario failed as the output

Answer (score 0):

Does the order of results matter? If not then you can use **execute_async** in this way:

```
# Submit an asynchronous query for execution.
cur.execute_async(query)

# Retrieve the results.
cur.get_results_from_sfqid(query_id)
results = cur.fetchall()
print(f'{results[0]}')
```

See more examples [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#examples-of-asynchronous-queries)

Comment: Not sure where i'm going wrong. But my code jumps straight to the else part
    for row in all_rows[1:4]:
     scenario = row[1].value
     query = row[2].value
     if_execute = row[3].value
     if if_execute == 'Y':
      try:
       df=cur.execute_async(query)
       cur.get_results_from_sfqid(query_id)
       df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
      except:
       print(scenario," Failed")
       #print(results[0])
      else:
       df[0].to_csv(output path)

Comment: That is normal if you did not get any error in the try block, the else is executed automatically.

Comment: my apologies for the typo, it goes for the except block instead of else